# Appending elements to a list based on condition

Tags: python, list, loops, if-statement, set

I was trying to append few elements to a list  `list_accepted_outsidenestant`. When i try to print the list `list_accepted_outsidenestant`, i get: `list_accepted_outsidenestant- [([971, 977, 728, 740], set([728, 977, 971, 740]))]`. The list is showing a list and set with same elements. Can anyone pointout the mistake i am doing? Because of this, i am getting an error: 
`set_accepted_outsidenest_antlist = set(list_accepted_outsidenestant
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

I have shown part of code only relevant to the current question.

```
def leo(tag_data):
    available_ants_outside = []
    ori = []
    for id, (x, y) in tag_data:
        available_ants_outside.append(id)
        if for_coordinates_outside_nest((x, y)) is True:
            ori.append(id)
    return ori


def virgo(tag_data):
    available_ants_inside = []
    list_insidenest_ant_id = []
    set_inside_nest_ant_id = set()
    for id, (x, y) in tag_data:
        available_ants_inside.append(id)
        if for_coordinates_inside_nest((x, y)) is True:
            list_insidenest_ant_id.append(id)
            set_inside_nest_ant_id = set(list_insidenest_ant_id)
            return list_insidenest_ant_id,set_inside_nest_ant_id

 def bambino(ori,list_insidenest_ant_id):
    list_accepted_outsidenestant = []                       
    set_accepted_outsidenest_antlist = set()
    set_accepted_insidenest_antlist = set()
    if len(list_accepted_outsidenestant) < num_accepted:
        if (len(ori) > 0) or (len(list_insidenest_ant_id) >0):
            list_accepted_outsidenestant.extend(ori[0:min(len(ori),             
            num_accepted-len(list_accepted_outsidenestant))])
            set_accepted_outsidenest_antlist = set(list_accepted_outsidenestant)  
            print "list_accepted_outsidenestant-" + str(list_accepted_outsidenestant)
            set_accepted_insidenest_antlist  = set(list_insidenest_ant_id)
    return set_accepted_outsidenest_antlist,set_list_outsideant_id,set_accepted_insidenest_antlist
```

Comment: This code is very hard to read. Please try and trace down where the problem is introduced and the behavior is different from what you expect.

Comment: In other words, please create a [mcve] to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @ChristianDean What i want is `list_accepted_outsidenestant = [971, 977, 728, 740]`

Comment: @philippd . I am just trying to extend the elements to a list `list_accepted_outsidenestant`. What i expect is; `list_accepted_outsidenestant = [971, 977, 728, 740]`. What i am getting is `list_accepted_outsidenestant- [([971, 977, 728, 740], set([728, 977, 971, 740]))] `

Comment: I am not going through your code and fix the problem for you.
At some point you append a tuple of sets to a list. You have to simply find out where and then convert the sets to lists and use the list.extend method or the list.append method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're appending a list to a list. 
You can either iterate over the list you want to add:

```
items_to_add = ori[0:min(len(ori),             
                   num_accepted-len(list_accepted_outsidenestant))]
for item in items_to_add:
    list_accepted_outsidenestant.append(item)
```

Or add the lists:

```
list_accepted_outsidenestant = list_accepted_outsidenestant + ori[0:min(len(ori), num_accepted-len(list_accepted_outsidenestant))]
```

Or as bruno pointed out (even better), extend the list.

```
list_accepted_outsidenestant.extend(ori[0:min(len(ori), num_accepted-len(list_accepted_outsidenestant))])
```

Comment: or use `list.extend(other_list)`.

Comment: Did not know this. Thanks

Comment: @JanZeiseweis I modified the code as suggested using `extent`. But the problem still persists

Comment: Than your problem might be the `ori` list. Where do you create this. Did you try to print ori before adding it to your existing list?

Comment: Python also has the `+=` operator which, if not *as* efficient as `.extend()`, is nearly so. (It's a shortcut for `list.__iadd__()`.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis I create them in the function `leo`. `leo = [971] [971,977] `

Answer (score 0):

**append** function add whole into other array 
**extend** function extend add array into previous array

```
In [1]: a = [1,2,3,4]

In [2]: b = [10,9,8,7,6]

In [3]: a.append(b)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 4, [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]]

In [5]: c = [1,2,3,4]

In [6]: c.extend(b)

In [7]: c
Out[7]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
```

Hope this code help you

Comment: I understood what you mentioned. I tried to use `extend` instead of append, but still the problem persists

Comment: can please explain what are trying in bit simpler way, because your code is very difficult to read.